# What options are available to encrypt the content of git repositories?

Tags: git, encryption

git-crypt, git secret were found. What is your personal preference and why?

A couple of months ago, I have applied git-crypt. It was quite hard to set it up and the secrets are stored as binaries. I wonder whether git-secret is less cumbersome to set up. What other options are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally am a fan of [Mozilla SOps](https://github.com/mozilla/sops), we've introduced it to two teams and it's gone down well both times, it has proven easy to implement both with local development and our CI/CD pipelines.

It has support for PGP/GPG to encrypt secrets but also supports Amazon KMS, GCP KMS and Azure KeyVault thus works well in an enterprise cloud-native infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is Kubernetes, I like [Sealed Secrets](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets)

It is what [Weave Cloud](https://www.weave.works/blog/storing-secure-sealed-secrets-using-gitops) uses to store configuration and do GitOps.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a good amount of time lately looking into the [GoDaddy open-source CRD called ExternalSecrets](https://github.com/godaddy/kubernetes-external-secrets). It's been pretty good to work with, it keeps the actual secret material in AWS Secrets Manager, and polls for changes. When a change is detected it creates/updates a Secret in your Kubernetes cluster. The only issue I've encountered is that you are mostly limited to using key/value pairs.